How was $m ≥ 8log(\frac{7|H|}{6})$ derived here?
Section 5.1 of Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms 2014 by Shai Shalev-Shwartz and Shai Ben-David states:


With probability of at least $\frac{1}{7}$ over the choice of $S ∼ D^m$ we have that $L_D(A(S)) ≥ \frac{1}{8}$. This theorem states that for every learner, there exists a task on which it fails, even though that task can be successfully learned by another learner. Indeed, a trivial successful learner in this case would be an ERM learner with the hypothesis class $H = \{f\}$, or more generally, ERM with respect to any finite hypothesis class that contains f and whose size satisfies the equation $m ≥ 8log(\frac{7|H|}{6}$) (see Corollary 2.3).


Also according to the book:

COROLLARY 2.3 Let H be a finite hypothesis class. Let $\delta \in (0, 1)$ and $\epsilon > 0$ and let $m$ be an integer that satisfies
$m ≥ \frac{log(\frac{|H|}{\delta})}{\epsilon}$. Then, for any labeling function, $f$, and for any distribution, $D$, for which the
realizability assumption holds (that is, for some $h \in H, L_{(D,f)}(h) = 0$), with probability of at least $1 − \delta$ over the choice of an i.i.d. sample $S$ of size $m$, we have that for every ERM hypothesis, $h_S$, it holds that
$L_{(D,f)}(h_S) ≤ \epsilon$.

I am trying to understand how $m ≥ 8log(\frac{7|H|}{6})$ was derived.
$\delta$ is the probability of failure which is when the generalization error, $L_D(A(S))$, is greater than or equal to $\epsilon$. Therefore $\delta = \frac{1}{7}$ and $\epsilon = \frac{1}{8}$. Substituting this into COROLLARY 2.3 one gets:
$m ≥ \frac{log(\frac{|H|}{\frac{1}{7}})}{\frac{1}{8}} = 8log(7|H|)$.
Where is the 6 coming from in this case?
I understand that if $\delta = \frac{6}{7}$ we would get $8log(\frac{7|H|}{6})$ but $\frac{6}{7}$ is $1 - \delta$ which is the probability of success and not the probability of failure.

You actually need to substitute $\delta=6/7$ to account for the extra "$6$", since in COROLLARY 2.3 to arrive at the minimum training sample size $m$ required for another ERM learner $E$ with a finite hypothesis class $H$ that contains $f$ to successfully learn the failed task which is tried by an arbitrary classification learner $A$ whose failure when samples are i.i.d. generated from a specific joint-distribution $D$ is proved by the No-Free-Lunch theorem 5.1, in the sense that with probability at least $1-\delta$ the successful ERM learner $E$'s true risk is below $\epsilon$.
We can arrive at $\delta=6/7$ from the hint of exercise 1 of the same chapter of the book as follows. First we need Lemma B.1 which basically says that, $\forall a \in (0, 1), \forall r.v. Z.(Z \in [0,1] \land \mathbb{E}[Z]=\mu) \to \mathbb{P}[Z>1-a] \ge \frac{\mu-(1-a)}{a} \land \mathbb{P}[z>a] \ge \mu-a$
Then from the critical result (5.2) as $\mathbb{E}[L_D(A(S))] \ge 1/4$, we can substitute $Z=L_D(A(S)), \mu \ge 1/4$ along with $a=7/8, a=1/8$ to Lemma B.1, then we can easily obtain both $\mathbb{P}[Z>1/8] \ge 1/7$ and $\mathbb{P}[Z>1/8] \ge 1/8$, so finally we merge them and get a single result for the failed arbitrary learner $A$ as $\mathbb{P}[L_D(A(S))>1/8] \ge 1/7$, which implies on the contrary the successful ERM learner $E$'s true risk must be bounded by $\mathbb{P}[L_D(E(S)) \le 1/8] \ge 1/7$ since  for each case of sample $S$ with size $m$ drawn i.i.d. from $D$ where $A$ fails ($L_D(A(S))>1/8$) $E$ succeeds ($L_D(E(S)) \le 1/8$), so $\delta=6/7$ in the sense that with probability at least $1/7$ the successful ERM learner $E$'s true risk is below $1/8$.

Not sure I follow your reasoning. If we substitute δ = 6/7, that means that the probability of failure (in this case having a generalization error more than 1/8) is 6/7. However, it is stated that P(L_D(A(S)) >= 1/8) is at least 1/7. This means that P(failure) >= 1/7 which implies that  δ = 1/7

Your interpretation of failure is relative, as explained in my answer's last paragraph that the unavoidable failure of the free-lunch learner A corresponds to the success of a ERM learner E after learning from at least $m$ training samples in your quotation expressed as $P[L_D(E(S))≤1/8]≥1/7$ which is in the form of the usual 'success' version of PAC learning you can count on to match the $δ$ term.

A simpler way to think about this is that we are calculating an "at least one" probability. This is done by calculating the converse probability (6/7) and then using 1-p() to find what we really needed. That's where the 6/7 comes from.
